# Insert readAsDataURL in [img]base64[/img] tag

Tags: javascript, bbcode

My code, i have Jquery:

```
<div class="form-row">          
<input class="form-group col-md-6" id="fileinput" type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="readURL(this);" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="content">Message</label>
<textarea id="content" name="content" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Écrivez un message ..."></textarea>
</div>

<script>
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
$("#fileinput").attr("src", e.target.result);
$("#content").val(e.target.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}   
</script>
```

I want to add the base64 img in a bbcode editor (textarea is #content).
Actually is work, but i want to have this:

[img]data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...[/img]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've successfully included jQuery as your script suggests, and your HTML looks a bit like this (simplified):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="file"/>
    <img id="content"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then a script like this will do what you want:

```
$(function() {
  function readURL() {
    // Grabbing the DOM object, so that the code follows your general pattern
    input = $(this)[0];
    if (input.files && input.files.length) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        // The attribute you want to change on an img tag is "src" not "val"
        $("#content").attr("src", reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
  // Bind the readURL function to the change event on our file input
  $("#file").change(readURL);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Joundill, Sorry I'm not given more information.
I edited my message for more information.
It is to integrate it into a BBcode editor

Comment: Note that the `<input>` and `<img>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash in HTML and never have.

Comment: Yeah, it's just syntactic sugar to show they're void tags. The W3C HTML5 spec allows for them:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags

I don't think it's worth being overly pedantic with removing slashes unless you're looking to save bytes (in which case the html should all be uglified and minified anyway).